# How to read XML into an ADODB.Stream object from the output of a SQL stored procedure that execs query FOR XML Auto

Tags: sql, xml, stored-procedures, stream, adodb

I have a stored procedure that returns a recordset (one column that has an XSLT stored in it) and an XML document.

The query is basically:

```
SELECT abc, 123
FROM TABLE_A
FOR XML AUTO
```

I need to call the stored procedure from a VBA application, presumably using ADO. I only found a couple examples doing a google search and none seemed to work.

Here's my "code":

```
Dim oConn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim oRS As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim oStream As New ADODB.Stream
Dim xml As MSXML2.DOMDocument60

Dim strXSLT As String
Dim strXML As String
Dim oFSO As New FileSystemObject
Dim TS As TextStream

oConn.ConnectionString = "Provider='sqloledb';Data Source='[myServer]';" & _
    "Initial Catalog='[myDB]';Integrated Security='SSPI';"

oConn.Open

Set oRS = oConn.Execute("exec dbo.sp_mySproc @Person ='" & gStrUserID & "', @Dash='Main'")

If Not (oRS.BOF And oRS.EOF) Then
    Set TS = oFSO.CreateTextFile("M:\Desktop\testMain.XSL", True)
    TS.Write oRS(0).Value
    TS.Close

    Set oRS = oRS.NextRecordset
    xml.loadXML oRS.Fields(oRS.Fields(0).Name)
    Set pi = xml.createProcessingInstruction("xml", _
         "version=""1.0"" encoding=""" & rst.Fields("XMLEncoding") & """")
    xml.insertBefore pi, xml.firstChild
    xml.Save "M:\Desktop\testMain.XML"


Set TS = oFSO.CreateTextFile("M:\Desktop\testMain.XML", True)
TS.Write "<?xml version=" & Chr(22) & "1.0" & Chr(22) & "?>" & vbCrLf & "<?xml-stylesheet type=" & Chr(22) & "text/xsl" & Chr(22) & " href=" & Chr(22) & "testmain.xsl" & Chr(22) & "?>" & vbCrLf
TS.Write oStream.ReadText
TS.Close
```

Everything works fine in that it will execute the stored procedure, get the XSL from the recordset and save it to disk but dies miserably after I do the `oRS.NextRecordset`.

Actually my code has two different attempts to save the XML; using a `TextStream` and a `DOMDocument60` (neither work).  Any ideas would be appreciated...

Mike

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of trial and error I found a solution:

```vb
Private Function GetXML(myConnection As ADODB.Connection, Sproc As String, XSLSuccess As Boolean, GUID As String, Optional Param2 As String = "") As Boolean
Dim sStreamQuery As New ADODB.Stream
Dim cmCmd As New ADODB.Command
Dim strQuery As String
Dim sResponseStream As New ADODB.Stream
Dim strXML As String
Dim oFSO As New FileSystemObject
Dim TS As TextStream

Set cmCmd.ActiveConnection = myConnection

' Set up the Template Query
strQuery = "<ROOT xmlns:sql='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-sql'>"
strQuery = strQuery & "<sql:header>"
strQuery = strQuery & "<sql:param name='Param1'>" & gStrParam1 & "</sql:param>"
If gStrParam2 <> "" Then
    strQuery = strQuery & "<sql:param name='Param2'>" & gStrParam2 & "</sql:param>"
End If
strQuery = strQuery & "</sql:header>"
strQuery = strQuery & "<sql:query >"
If gStrParam2 <> "" Then
    strQuery = strQuery & "exec dbo." & Sproc & " @Param1, @Param2"
Else
    strQuery = strQuery & "exec dbo." & Sproc & " @Param1"
End If
strQuery = strQuery & "</sql:query>"
strQuery = strQuery & "</ROOT>"

' Read the template query into the Stream
'Set sStreamQuery = New Stream
sStreamQuery.Open
sStreamQuery.WriteText strQuery, adWriteChar
sStreamQuery.Position = 0

' Associate the stream with the command and set the
' dialect to XML to interpret it
Set cmCmd.CommandStream = sStreamQuery
cmCmd.Dialect = "{5D531CB2-E6Ed-11D2-B252-00C04F681B71}"

' Create a stream to handle the response
sResponseStream.Open

' Can also be a response object in an ASP page
cmCmd.Properties("Output Stream") = sResponseStream

cmCmd.Execute , , adExecuteStream

strXML = Replace(sResponseStream.ReadText, "<ROOT xmlns:sql=" & Chr(34) & "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-sql" & Chr(34) & ">", "", 1)
strXML = Replace(strXML, "</ROOT>", "", 1)

Set TS = oFSO.CreateTextFile(gstrPath & GUID & ".XML", True)
TS.Write "<?xml version=" & Chr(34) & "1.0" & Chr(34) & "?>" & vbCrLf
If XSLSuccess Then
    TS.Write "<?xml-stylesheet type=" & Chr(34) & "text/xsl" & Chr(34) & " href=" & Chr(34) & GUID & ".xsl" & Chr(34) & "?>" & vbCrLf
End If
TS.Write strXML
TS.Close

Set TS = Nothing
Set oFSO = Nothing


sResponseStream.Close
sStreamQuery.Close

Set responseStream = Nothing
Set sStreamQuery = Nothing
Set cmCmd = Nothing

End Function
```